# How to add headers to Firebase HttpsCallable function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to add some custom headers to a Firebase HttpsCallable function when calling from client side. But the firebase.functions.HttpsCallable does not provide any way to customize headers. The second param "*options*" only support "*timeout*".

Is there any workaround or alternative solution to add headers to a Firebase function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the [protocol specification](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable-reference) for `https.onCall`, you can only have the following headers when calling a Callable Cloud Function:

> **Required:** `Content-Type: application/json`
>   An optional ; `charset=utf-8`
>   is allowed.
>
> **Optional:** `Authorization: Bearer <token>`
>   A Firebase Authentication
>   user ID token for the logged-in user making the request. The backend
>   automatically verifies this token and makes it available in the
>   handler's `context`. If the token is not valid, the request is rejected.
>
> **Optional:** `Firebase-Instance-ID-Token: <iid>`
>   The Instance ID token
>   from the Firebase client SDK. This must be a string. This is available
>   in the handler's `context`. It is particularly useful for sending push
>   notifications.

And the doc adds that:

> **If any other headers are included, the request is rejected**

---

On the other hand, with [HTTP Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/http-events) you can add any custom header that you want. However, by using an HTTP Cloud Function, you'll loose the advantages of a Callable Cloud Function (i.e. Firebase Authentication and FCM tokens are automatically included in requests and
the functions.https.onCall trigger automatically deserializes the request body and validates auth tokens).